# Open, save and close an Excel file from the command prompt without interaction

Tags: python, excel, vba

I have an Excel file that needs to be automatically modified (with a Python script) and also be available for manual modifications. It has several sheets, each containing a single table and containing formulas.
My script opens the Excel file with `openpyxl`, to avoid breaking the structure inside the tables and automatically modify some rows in some specific sheets. I use `openpyxl` because I need the Excel file to be manually modified the same way, meaning that users can open it, add for instance a new line, which will extend the table and fill the formulas automatically, normal behavior of tables in Excel.

After saving in Python, I need to read it in Tableau Prep, a program for data preparation. This program cannot read my formulas after I save the Excel file with `openpyxl`. It only reads if I manually open the modified Excel, save it without any manual modification and close it. I immediately see that the size of the file changes, meaning that `openpyxl` saves in a different way than Excel, so Excel re-organizes itself.

I need this script to do everything automatically, without manually opening the file at the end.

I am searching for a way to open an Excel file via command prompt, save it and close it. I found a simple VBA macro:

```vb
Sub SaveAndCloseWithoutModifications()
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    ThisWorkbook.Save
    ThisWorkbook.Close
End Sub
```

I did not succeed to make it work from the command line. It opens the Excel and does nothing automatically.

I tried:

```
start excel.exe excelfile.xlsm /mSaveAndCloseWithoutModifications
```

Comment: You need to rethink your ETL process. For starters, it's Tableau's job to calculate measures. That's why it exists - for fast calculation and aggregation. It will be orders of magnitude faster than trying to execute the same formulas in Python with a formula engine

Comment: The problem is not in the ETL process. The excel file is my source, and I cannot change its structure, only add or modify info into each table (my sheets). The ETL part is done by Tableau Prep, but the problem is that is not reading the formulas if they come from openpyxl

Comment: You misunderstood what I wrote. The *calculations* should be performed by Tableau, not Excel. Tableau exists because it performs in-memory calculations fast, over a lot of data. Not because of its reports or visualizations. Otherwise it would be no better than any other reporting tool

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for your comments. I didn't try you vbs approach, but thanks @z32a7ul.
I managed to solve the problem by doing the following:
My xlsm file has a module with the code:

```
Sub SaveAndCloseWithoutModifications()
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    ThisWorkbook.Save
End Sub
```

Then, in python, after having modified and saved the file with openpyxl, I do:

```
import win32com.client as win32
excel = win32.Dispatch('Excel.Application')
workbook = excel.Workbooks.Open(filepath)
excel.Run('SaveAndCloseWithoutModifications')
excel.Quit()
```

Answer (score 1):

I would use vbs for this:

```
Set app = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
Set wb = app.Workbooks.Open("excelfile.xlsm")
app.Visible = True ' For debugging
wb.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1").Value = 1 ' For debugging enter a unique number
wb.Save
WScript.Echo "Press OK to quit Excel" ' For debugging
app.Quit
```

If you have not used vbs before, just create a plain text file, name it as "something.vbs", and put the above code in it. From cmd it can be started either as `something.vbs` or as `WScript something.vbs`